# ¿Qué diferencias hay entre library() y require() a la hora de cargar un paquete?

Tags: r

A la hora de cargar un paquete hay dos formas de hacerlo: `library()` y `require()`. ¿Qué diferencias hay, si las hay, entre ambos métodos?

Traducción libre y reelaboración de: **[What is the difference between require() and library()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595512/what-is-the-difference-between-require-and-library)**

Comment: Porque haces una pregunta si sabes la respuesta creo que no es la idea de stack overflow amigo

Comment: @LuisDanielRoviraContreras Todo lo contrario Luis, SO alienta a las personas a que respondan sus propias preguntas, de hecho al formular tienes la opción de escribir la respuesta al mismo tiempo.

Comment: a okay no lo sabia amigo pensé que eran solo preguntas y no auto respuestas gracias por el dato

Comment: @LuisDanielRoviraContreras Es totalmente respetable contestar tus propias preguntas. Sugiero que te des una vuelta por el sitio Meta y veas todas las discusiones que se dan al respecto, de igual forma el centro de ayuda para que conozcas el alcance completo del sitio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tanto `?library` como `?requiere` apuntan a la misma ayuda. Ambas hacen lo mismo: cargan un determinado paquete en la sesión activa. La diferencia de ambas, se detalla en la ayuda:

> library(package) and require(package) both load the namespace of the
>   package with name package and attach it on the search list. require is
>   designed for use inside other functions; it returns FALSE and gives a
>   warning (rather than an error as library() does by default) if the
>   package does not exist

Básicamente:

#### `require()`:

- Retorna `FALSE` y emite un `warning` en caso de no poder cargar el paquete
- No detiene la eventual ejecución del script
- Se muestra por consola, aparte de los eventuales mensajes del paquete, el texto `Loading required package: <paquete>` que se puede eliminar mediante `quietly = TRUE`

#### `library()`:

- Emite un `error` en caso de no poder cargar el paquete
- Por defecto no retorna ningún valor, a menos que usemos el parámetro `logical.return = TRUE`
- Detiene la ejecución del script

El uso de `require()` por sobre `library()` es un poco difuso, normalmente los paquetes se cargan al comienzo de un script y es lógico que si no se puede cargar no se continue la ejecución por lo que `library()` sería la opción adecuada, por otro lado eventualmente podríamos encontrarnos con estos escenarios:

- Intentar cargar un paquete y en caso de error usar otro de una funcionalidad similar
- Intentar cargar un paquete y en caso de error intentar instalarlo, por ejemplo:

  ```
  if (!require(package, character.only=T, quietly=T)) {
      install.packages(package)
      library(package, character.only=T)
  }
  ```

Para estos casos el uso de `require()` se justificaría ya que no se detiene la ejecución.

fuente: [What is the difference between require() and library()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595512/what-is-the-difference-between-require-and-library)